# Do OS GUI's have a different shell than the command line interpreter?

Tags: command-line, shell, operating-systems, gui

This is a very general question but I am having a difficult time finding clarification. My question is: do OS GUI's have a different shell than the command line interpreter? When I was reading about shells on the Wikipedia page it says below the Microsoft Windows section that "most OS shells in Microsoft windows are not command line interpreters". I understand that in the modern day most people use a GUI to interact with their OS and that if an OS has a GUI then the GUI serves as the operating system's primary shell.

So here is where my confusion comes in. On Windows 10, for example, you can access the command line interface and enter commands to the OS if you so choose. Does the command line interface on an OS with a GUI have the same shell as its respective GUI?

Comment: windows (and any other modern OS) have a number of shells that are invoked for whatever type of input needs processed. There isn't a "THE shell". A shell is an Instance of a program that takes input for processing. if you run a vbscript in cmd.exe using `cscript myscript.vbs` you are invoking a cscript shell, and executing your script. The run bar is its own shell, as is each command window. Each shell maintains its own environment, as is evidenced by the behavior of the SET and SETX verbs which modify environment for just one, or many other shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people of the Windows tradition use the term "shell" in a very broad sense to mean the user interface of the OS, whether it be graphical or command-line.

So in Windows, the GUI **is** the "shell".

Some of this goes back to an old MS-DOS semi-graphical (text-mode graphics) file manager app called "DOS Shell", that attempted to shield the user from having to use the actual DOS command prompt. So if this file manager app was a "shell" around DOS, then later Windows file managers and program managers and process managers and desktop environments and GUI systems were all also "shells" around the OS, presenting a more pleasant user interface.

In the Unix world, command-line interpreters are shells, and GUI/windowing/desktop environments are never considered shells of any sort. macOS terminology follows this model. The Finder is not a shell: bash is a shell.

> Does the command line interface on an OS with a GUI have the same shell as its respective GUI?

I suppose in MS Windows terms, the command line interpreter is part of the shell, just like Windows Explorer and the Start Menu are parts of the shell. Just replace "shell" with "user interface" and you'll understand the way the term is used among some Windows academics. Is the command-line user interface part of the OS's user interface? Yes. Then it's part of the shell.

Comment: Maybe this is just more semantics, but when you say the command line is part of interface are you saying that the command line in a GUI shell-led OS like Windows is part of the shell but not THE shell?

Comment: you can run one shell in another. for instance in linux in a Bash shell, you can invoke a python shell or sh or ksh or ash or dash whatever else. The only "special" shells are the ones the OS automatically loads at boot, and that is a property of the OS configuration, not the shell itself. you can make windows boot to a command prompt if you want (or at least you used to be able to; haven't tried it in some time). so its not unusual for a cmd.exe shell to invoke a powershell.exe shell, all within an explorer.exe shell.